# Could YouTube save bandwidth when the browser tab is inactive? (cut the video, maintain the audio?)

Tags: youtube, bandwidth

Tons of people use YouTube just to listen to music. And, in many cases, their browser defaults to a high bitrate video, which is totally wasted bandwidth if they've switched tabs away from the video (back to their work, etc).

Would it be feasible for YouTube to deactivate video (or at least downgrade the quality) when the browser tab is inactive?

It seems like, if feasible, this optimization would have the potential of significantly reducing traffic.

Does it already do something like this?

Comment: Not sure this is a good question for this site. Is it feasible? Possibly, but we have no insight into the development required. You're really just asking us to speculate. How would you pick an answer as "correct"?

Comment: True, it's a speculative question. Didn't know if someone had insight into how the system works. Seems like it could be a cool optimization.